# package is not a sf command?

Tags: salesforcedx, managed-package, package, sfdx-plugin, sf

Salesforce has recently deprecated the `sfdx force:package:version:create` command. `sfdx` asks us to use the package version create command instead.

Running `sf package version create`, however, also generates an error:

> Warning: package is not a sf command. Did you mean plugins? [y/n]:  ›
> Error: Run sf help for a list of available commands.

The documentation is not clear. Why is `sf package` not available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, `sf package *` commands are available relatively recently, since the [`1.66.2 (Feb 22, 2023)`](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/blob/main/releasenotes/sf/README.md#1662-feb-22-2023) version of the `sf` executable of Salesforce CLI.

From [`Salesforce CLI Release Notes (sf Commands)`](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/blob/main/releasenotes/sf/README.md):

> **NEW**: We now install some plugins just when you need them, rather than include them automatically in a Salesforce CLI release. Let's use the updated plugin-packaging as an example. The plugin isn't included in `sf` by default, although `sf` knows about it. When you run one of the plugin's commands for the first time, such as `sf package version create`, Salesforce CLI installs the **latest released version** of the plugin and then runs the command. The installation happens automatically, although we display a little message so you know what's going on. From then on, run any of the commands contained in the plugin as usual. And when you next run `sfdx update`, if the just-in-time plugin has released a new version, then it's also updated. Just a little just-in-time magic!

I believe that you should update `sf`:

> If you installed `sf` with the `sfdx` installers, run `sfdx update` to update to the latest available stable version. Run `sfdx update stable-rc` to update to the release candidate. To return to the `stable` version, run `sfdx update stable`.

> If you installed `sf` with `npm`, run `npm install @salesforce/cli@latest-rc -g` to update to the release candidate. To return to the `stable` version, run `npm install @salesforce/cli@latest -g`.